# CarrierWave Multiple File Upload Rails Unit Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, carrierwave

I have been banging my head with Carrierwave. I finally was able to get carrier wave to upload multiple files by adding the master branch for Carrierwave to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave', github:'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
```

I used it for a model called Product and I did this.
Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :avatar, ProductUploader
end
```

And I essentially followed the rules and was able to upload multiple files all while having each file iterate through the create method in my `products_controller.rb` and creating a new Product instance for each file being uploaded.

Now. Here comes the Testing. Before, when only one file was being uploaded I was able to use,

```
test "should create product" do
  login
  excel_filename = 'files/product_create_test.xls'
  file = fixture_file_upload(excel_filename, 'application/excel')
  assert_difference('Product.count') do
    post :create, product: {:file_url => file}
  end
```

But now, after adding the ability to upload multiple files, it seems like fixture_file_upload is not working properly.
I am getting this error:

```
 ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
    ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
        test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
        test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:53:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

I am not sure how to go around this. Like I said, when I had

```
 gem 'carrierwave'
```

the previous test worked fine. Has anyone ever encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the problem was. In order to make it so that my fixture file uploads did not actually save in my test enviroment, I followed this article, http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2014/using-test-fixtures-with-carrierwave/#comment_768.

Here it tells you to add the following to your test_helper file

```
class CarrierWave::Mount::Mounter
  def store!
    # Not storing uploads in the tests
  end
end
```

This essentially tells your testing environment not to store the uploaded fixtures anywhere. Anyway, this piece of code does not fly well with the addition of the carrier wave master branch for multiple file uploads. I ended up uncommenting it and despite the fact that is stores the uploaded files, my tests pass.